# Using D3's path generators. How to assign data to them?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm currently trying to implement a line-graph with D3.js

The D3-documentation contains the following examples:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .interpolate("basis");

g.append("path")
    .attr("d", line);
```

... and says "Whatever data is bound to g (in this example) will be passed to the line instance."

What is meant with "bounding data"?

I've got the following code which works:

```
var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
                 .x(function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i);
                 })
                 .y(function(d) {
                    return HEIGHT - yScale(d);
                 })
                 .interpolate('basis');
    var lineVal = lineGen(data);

    svg.append('path').attr('d', lineVal)
                      .attr({
                        'fill': 'none',
                        'stroke': 'black',
                        'stroke-width': '3'
                      });
```

With lineGen(data) I generate a string. Then I assign this string to the attr-setter.

But the way which is explained in the official documentation doesn't work.

What do I have to do to bound my data to the SVG element directly?

svg.data(data) doesn't work. I've tried that already.

**UPDATE**

I've found the solution in a tutorial.

```
// Data-structure. In this case an 
//   one-dimensional array.
var data = [ 22, 31, 29, 32, 21, 38, 30 ];

svg.append('path')
    // Assign the data-structure as ONE
    //   element an array-literal.
    .data([data])
    .attr('d', lineGen)
    .attr({
      'fill': 'none',
      'stroke': 'black',
      'stroke-width': '3'
    });
```

By assigning the data-structure as an element of an array-literal the 
**whole** data are bound to **one** element.

An alternative to this technique is the usage of selection.datum().
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#datum

Answer (score 0):

In d3 data is bond to the selections. You can use enter and exit selections to create new nodes for incoming data and remove outgoing nodes that are no longer needed.

In your example, you should try as shown below.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .interpolate("basis");

g.selectAll("path") //Selects all the elements that match the specific selector, here elements having path tag
    .data(data)  //The data operator joins the specified array of data with the current selection.
    .enter() //The enter selection contains placeholders for any missing elements. Here it has placeholders for n path elements where n is the length of data array.
    .append("path") //For each placeholder element created in the previous step, a path element is inserted.
    .attr("d", line); //The first param of line function would be the data (corresponding array element) bond to the current path element. And the second param is the data index.
```

To know more about data binding in d3 refer : [Binding-data-to-dom-elements](https://www.dashingd3js.com/binding-data-to-dom-elements).

**Edit :**
To create a single path element with data bonded, try as shown below.

```
g.append("path")
 .datum(dataObj) //Where dataObj is data[i]
 .attr("d", line);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your effort. I really appreciate it. But there must be something else ... Let's say I have an array with six elements. enter() gives six path elements which are appended in the following step. Firebug console: <svg height="500" width="1000">
<path fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="5">
<path fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="5">
<path fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="5">
<path fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="5">
<path fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="5">
<path fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="5">
</svg>

Comment: But for constructing a line ONE path element with a d-attribute is needed: http://www.svgbasics.com/paths.html The data from the array have to be put into the value of the d-attribute.